# The Doppler Effect Relating to Light

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, speed-of-light

I've seen a lot of examples calculating the Doppler shift with regards to sound using the equation

$$F_\mathrm{observed}=F_\mathrm{transmitted}\frac{340 \pm v}{340 \pm v}$$

This equation takes into consideration both the observer and the source moving, and the Doppler shift for light takes a similar equation,

$$F_\mathrm{observed}=F_\mathrm{transmitted}\frac{c}{c \pm v}\left(\frac{1}{γ}\right)$$

This is the most popular example because we can actually use this to explain the universe expanding! I was wondering what the effects of the observer moving towards the source would be? Seeing the similarity between the two equations, I've assumed,

$$F_\mathrm{observed}=F_\mathrm{transmitted}\frac{c±v}{c±v}\left(\frac{1}{γ}\right)$$

Would I be corrected to make these assumptions?

Comment: It's rather more complicated than that. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect) as a starting point.

Comment: Feynman lectures: http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_34.html, 34-6 Doppler Effect. Feynman considers both cases - emitter is moving in observer's frame and vice versa. Starting from: " Suppose, now, that the source is standing still and is emitting waves at frequency ω0, while the observer is moving with speed v toward the source."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the equation for the Doppler shift of sound has terms for the transmitter and observer is that both have a velocity with respect to the medium that sound travels through--for example, air for sound. The air that transmits sound provides a common reference point for the transmitter and observer to measure their velocities.

Light, on the other hand, does not need a medium to propagate. It travels through empty space just fine. In this case, there is nothing to provide an independent reference frame for the transmitter and observer to measure their velocities. There is no such thing as an absolute velocity through space. The transmitter and observer only have velocities relative to each other. The observer is at rest in the observer's point of view, so only the transmitter is moving. Thus, the equation for the Doppler shift of light only includes the transmitter velocity. Equivalently, to make the term more symmetric, you could say that the velocity is the rate of change of the distance between the transmitter and observer.